# Unambiguous inequality notation

Tags: inequality, notation

Suppose that I write
$$
  x^3x^4 \neq x^{12}
$$
in a journal paper, the journal being not a professional mathematical journal but a journal in an allied STEM field. Of course, maybe $x=1$, in which special case $x^3x^4 = x^{12}$, but this is not what I mean when I write the displayed inequality. What I mean is that to replace $x^3x^4$ by $x^{12}$ would be bad algebra.

To resolve, I have been including extra verbiage, as "In general, $x^3x^4 \neq x^{12}$." Does there exist a less verbose notation a STEM professional audience would recognize to mean, "In general, $x^3x^4 \neq x^{12}$," as opposed to, "Always, $x^3x^4 \neq x^{12}$"?

I am vaguely aware that symbols like $\neg$ with which my audience would be unfamiliar exist, but I probably do not know how to use $\neg$ properly, anyway. I am also aware that English phrases are often preferable to overly condensed mathematical notation. Nevertheless, I would like to improve my notation where I can; so what are my options, please?

For information, my draft's actual inequality is $$
[kv\,\nabla f_1(\mathbf r)]^2 \neq [kv]^2\,\nabla f_1^2(\mathbf r),
$$ but this wants explanation of my draft's intent by the notation $[\nabla f_1(\mathbf r)]^2 := \nabla f_1(\mathbf r)\cdot\nabla f_1(\mathbf r)$, which lies beyond the question's scope. Thus, at your discretion, the earlier $x^{12}$ example suffices as far as I know.

Comment: As polynomials, the product of $x^3$ and $x^4$ is $x^{3+4}$ and not $x^{3\cdot 4}$, so you could just say this. Still, $x^7=x^{12}$ for $x=1$, but $x^7\neq x^{12}$ in $K[x]$.

Comment: $\exists x : x^3 x^4 \neq x^{12}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. You are right, of course. My intent was to give a simple, obvious example, though. The actual inequality in my journal submission is too esoteric to be allowed to burden a SE question. Your suggestion unfortunately would not work in my esoteric case.

Comment: @CarlaCvekla Aha. I should have known. I would be glad to upvote your answer, if you submitted it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is to deny a putative [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)), so the most concise option is $x^3x^4\not\equiv x^{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

Answer, using this information from the OP's comment

> The actual inequality in my journal submission is too esoteric to be
> allowed to burden a SE question.

I suggest either

> The equality  $$ E_1 = E_2 $$ is true only in some special cases ...

or

> In general, $$ E_1 \ne E_2 $$ although in some special cases ...

The choice depends on the part you want to emphasize.

Comment: Some readers (though not necessarily you), seem possibly to be interested in my actual inequality. In case anyone cares, it is $[kv\nabla\!f_1(\mathbf r)]^2 \neq [kv]^2\nabla^2\!f_1(\mathbf r)$. As I said, it's too esoteric to bother readers here with, besides which the specific use of the symbol $\nabla$ would require extra explanation to readers outside North America. This is why my question uses $x^3x^4\neq x^{12}$ instead for an example. Thanks.

Comment: @thb $\nabla$ has the same meaning in the UK, at least.

Comment: @J.G. Does it? I did not know that. Long ago, during my first year of graduate school, a term project in a three-credit course had something to do with the ionosphere and the parabolic wave equation. Journal papers on the topic were available, but the only monograph I could find was by a British author, published (if I recall) by Elsevier. Unless I remember incorrectly, that author used $\nabla$ (or was it $\Delta$?) to represent a Laplacian second-order differential, which confused me and my study partner for hours until we figured it out. This is where I got the idea, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @thb What you might be thinking of is $\Delta:=\nabla^2$.